# How can I remotely extend provisioning profiles about to expire?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a number of Apple devices around the country with employees of mine that have custom apps.  Many of their provisioning profiles are about to expire.  How can I extend the expiration of those provisioning profiles without having to get my hands on the device.  I have a paid apple developer account.

Comment: Do you have a web server that you could host an updated .ipa for the users to install a new version of the apps with new provisioning profiles?  In the past you could email the users the .mobileprovision file, but I don't think that has worked since iOS 7.

Comment: The idea would be to renew the expiring provision without any action on their part, I mean, isn't it expiring on apple's server, I should be able to update that and it would simply automatically update on their device.

Comment: Well, the profile on the device is going to expire.  So you need to get a new provisioning profile on the device.  The only way I can think of to do this without user intervention would be through an MDM (Mobile Device Management) product.  Given that you are asking this, I'm assuming these devices have not been enrolled in an MDM profile, so this option is probably not out.  How do you get users to update to new versions of apps when they are released?